# Seg fault when trying to access member of structure array

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
typedef struct abc {
  unsigned int pref;
  unsigned int port;
  char *aRecordIp;
    int index;
    int count;
}abc_t;

typedef struct xyz {
        abc_t *ab;
        int index;
        int count;
}xyz_t;


int Lookup (char *lookup,xyz_t **handle) {

*handle = (xyz_t *)malloc(sizeof(xyz_t *));
(*handle)->ab = (abc_t *) malloc(5*sizeof(abc_t *));
//
(*handle)->ab[0].pref = 10;  //seg fault here
}


void *myhandle;
```

// this is a void pointer and I cannot change that as it is used elsewhere too

```
char lookup;


Lookup(&lookup, &myhandle);
```

// I get a warning here which is obviuous but how do I take care of that

Comment: Please don't correct the error in your question; it will make the answers look clueless. Think of the future readers.

Comment: @wildplasser But if it wasn't actually the cause of the error - as stated in a comment - it is ok to correct it if the edit reflects the actual state.

Comment: I don't care. All the answers are about the extra asterixes. If the actual problem was caused by something not in the fragment, the question would not make any sense anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is a good reason to prefer the `ptr = malloc (count * sizeof *ptr);` notation; **the compiler already knows** the type and size of an expression, so **you won't have to specify that again**:

```
int Lookup (char *lookup,xyz_t **handle) {

  *handle = malloc(sizeof **handle);
  (*handle)->ab = malloc(5 * sizeof *(*handle)->ab );
  (*handle)->ab[0].pref = 10;  //seg fault here
}
```

Or, using array notation (just to avoid the ugly `*(*handle)`) :

```
int Lookup (char *lookup,xyz_t **handle) {

  *handle = malloc(sizeof **handle);
  (*handle)->ab = malloc(5 * sizeof (*handle)->ab[0] );
  (*handle)->ab[0].pref = 10;  //seg fault here
}
```

Note: I also removed the casts, which are not needed and potentially dangerous.

Also note that this *stylistic* correction will fix **both** the errors.

Comment: that did not fix seg fault for me

Answer (score 1):

```
(*handle)->ab = (abc_t *) malloc(5*sizeof(abc_t *));
```

Should probably be:

```
(*handle)->ab = (abc_t *) malloc(5*sizeof(abc_t));
```

In C you don't need that cast though, since `void*` casts implicitly to any kind of pointer, so:

```
(*handle)->ab = malloc(5*sizeof(abc_t));
```

is enough.

Also, make sure you check the return value of all `malloc` calls.

Comment: Oops, I have edited it, it is actually `(*handle)->ab = (abc_t *) malloc(5*sizeof(abc_t));` and I still get a seg fault

Answer (score 1):

`(abc_t *) malloc(5*sizeof(abc_t *));` should be `(abc_t *) malloc(5*sizeof(abc_t));`. You are requesting for space of 5 pointers rather than space for 5 strucures.

Comment: That did not help and the seg fault still exists